# How do these items which improve Dragonbreath stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, powers

What are the cumulative effects of the following?

- Ring of the Dragonborn Emperor (Adventurer's Vault)
- Arkhosian Scepter (Player's Handbook Races - Dragonborn)
- Paragon Path: Ninefold Master lvl 11 feature (Player's Handbook Races - Dragonborn)
- Dual Implement Spellcaster (Arcane Power)

I'll also have Ancient Soul, so the dragon breath will be an arcane attack no matter what.

I'm trying to determine a few things here related to my dragon breath attack.  In particular, what would my total damage be for my dragon breath if I am holding a +6 Dagger in each hand with the Arkhosian Scepter on my person? If I'm holding a +6 dagger and a +6 Arkhosian Scepter in my hands only? And lastly, are there any redundancies in any of this where I could ignore one of the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break it down point by point.

- Ring of the Dragonborn Empror - Item bonus to damage on DB
- Arkhosian Scepter - Add implement Enhancement bonus to attack and damage on DB
- Ninefold Master - Add implement Enhancement bonus to damage on DB
- Dual Implement Spellcaster - Add implement Enhancement bonus for offhand implement to damage on arcane powers.

Looks to me like the Arkhosian Scepter is redundant here wrt damage on the dragon breath. Provided you're proficient with daggers as implements the +6 daggers work identically to the +6 scepter on damage, but the scepter allows for the addition on the attack role in addition to the damage.

As far as total damage, from the items you listed above you'd get a +17. (6+6+5)

Answer (score 1):

The total damage calculated by [wax eagle](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1084/wax-eagle) is most likely correct, but not the reasoning:

- Ring of the Dragonborn Emperor - +5 Item bonus on DB
- Ninefold Master - +6 unnamed bonus to damage on DB, possibly 6+6, depending on your interpretation of the class feature. If you wield 2 implements, do you add both?
- Dual Implement Spellcaster - It does not add anything to DB, because of the wording of the feat, and the definition of *usable*:

  - "Both of your implements must be usable with this power, [...] to gain this benefit." None of your implements are *usable*, as DB is not an implement power.
  - "The implement keyword identifies a power that can be *used* with an implement". Rules compendium page 113
- Arkhosian Scepter - +6 unnamed bonus to attack and damage on DB. For the above mentioned reason the Scepter can not add its enhancement bonus to a non-implement power, it just gives a bonus without any category. So it must be unnamed.

If you are not holding the Scepter, it does not provide any bonuses, so Scepter + Dagger is clearly better for DB than Dagger + Dagger.

Comment: I'd argue the implements *are* usable with the power, I'm sort of buying that Ninefold master is untyped as it's the same wording as DIS.